# Mmanipulating through children to check the checkbox in a table row

Tags: jquery, checkbox, html-table

```
$("tr.clickable").each(function() {$(this).click(function() {
            $(this).children("td:first > input").is(":checked") ?
                    $(this).children("td:first > input").removeAttr("checked") :
                    $(this).children("td:first > input").attr("checked","checked");
        })});
```

this only checks the first row in my table (no matter which row I click on). How can I apply it so that it checks the input on the specific row I click on?

HTML:

```
    <tbody style="height: 500px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;">
                                                <tr id="row0" class="alternate clickable">
                        <td>                            <img width="11" height="11" title="This email failed to send." alt="Failed" src="images/error_warning.png">
                                                    <br>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="6751" name="emailCheck[]" class="emailCheck"></td>
                        <td><a href="user_settings.php?id=349">
                            wmiller                 </a></td>
                        <td>New Fin-iQ Message</td>
                        <td><span class="errorText">UNKNOWN</span></td>
                        <td>New Bulletin Notification</td>
                        <td>Jun. 07/10 10:14:39 am</td>
                        <td><a href="emails_report.php?action=re&amp;id=6751">Resend</a>
                            <br>
                            <a id="emailBodyToggle_6751" href="javascript:showEmail(6751)">Show</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
<tr id="emailBody_6751" style="display: none; text-align: left;" class="alternate">
                    <td colspan="7"><div>...</div></td>
                </tr>
                                                <tr id="row1" class=" clickable">
                    <td>                            <img width="11" height="11" title="This email failed to send." alt="Failed" src="images/error_warning.png">
                                                <br>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="6752" name="emailCheck[]" class="emailCheck"></td>
                    <td><a href="user_settings.php?id=350">
                        mholman                 </a></td>
                    <td>New Fin-iQ Message</td>
                    <td><span class="errorText">UNKNOWN</span></td>
                    <td>New Bulletin Notification</td>
                    <td>Jun. 07/10 10:14:39 am</td>
                    <td><a href="emails_report.php?action=re&amp;id=6752">Resend</a>
                        <br>
                        <a id="emailBodyToggle_6752" href="javascript:showEmail(6752)">Show</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr id="emailBody_6752" style="display: none; text-align: left;" class="">
                    <td colspan="7"><div>...</div></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Just to verify, all tr's ( #row1, #row2, etc i assume) have the class 'clickable' as well?

Comment: yes, all #row%ID%s have 'clickable'. i just extended the html at the end to illustrate that =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the call to .each() on your first selector.  jQuery uses "implied iteration" which means you can do things like this:

```
$('tr.clickable').click(function () { // Do things here. });
```

You should end up with a click function on each row that way.

After messing with your post on fiddle I get this to work:

```
$("tr.clickable").click(function() {
    $(this).find("td:first input").is(":checked") ? $(this).find("td:first input").removeAttr("checked") : $(this).find("td:first input").attr("checked","checked");
});
```

Comment: Great point.. Knew something didn't look 'right' with that code but couldn't put my finger on it. +1

Comment: i tried that before :( that's why i put each around it because it looked like it was only hitting the first element

Comment: This is a separate scoping issue that doesn't solve the content problem: http://jsfiddle.net/mH7NE/  While this is correct, it doesn't solve the problem :)

Comment: are you saying there's something wrong with jquery? very cool site, btw (jsfiddle)

Comment: There may be.  The original code sample seemed like it was correct to me as well.  I'm in the habit of avoiding the `>` addition to selectors most of the time (I find it's not usually required for what I'm attempting to accomplish) but I don't think it's presence accounts for the differences between `.find()` and `.children()` in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch your code around like this:

```
$("tr.clickable").click(function() {
    var cb = $("td:first > input", this)[0];
    cb.checked = !cb.checked;
});​
```

[You can view a demo on it here](http://jsfiddle.net/BTJPQ/2/).

This is cleaner/faster and still cross-browser compliant using the core JavaScript approach and the [`.checked` DOM attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_checked.asp), only using jQuery for selectors.

*Site note:* When binding a handler like [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) there's no need for a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), just call `.click()` directly and the function/handler you pass in will be bound to each matched element.

Comment: i had high hopes but still a nogo. edited main post with more html if it helps =S

Comment: @gsquare567: Updated the demo with your new markup, give it a go :)